# Google Sheets Vertical + Horizontal Lookup

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I would like to;

- Find a name in Column 'A', e.g. "Bob", which is in A5.
  On the row that "Bob" is in, Row 5;
- Find the cell that contains a specific text, e.g. "Age", which is in F5
- Grab the value in the adjacent cell, e.g. 45, which is in G5

So I need to find the name vertically, and then search for text horizontally and return the adjacent cell value. Unfortunately the only value that is always in the same column is 'name' in Column 'A'. The age number isn't always in Column 'G' which is why I need to first find the word "Age" and then grab the adjacent cell value.

I've done a great job of confusing myself here :) thanks for any help. I've tried various vlookup and hlookup combinations with no luck.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TWjkmnKyOEeqPEfnZAykp9jQTiAe4LbuhT1x_4hQwfY/edit

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ,filter(B:G,A:A=I2),
       index(Σ,xmatch("age",Σ)+1))
```

[image]

Comment: This appears to work - thank you so much! After seeing your suggested formula I'm glad i asked for help - I have never seen or used 'Let' before.